# How do I calculate a PCB embedded capacitor? (2 in series)

Tags: capacitor, pcb, pcb-design, capacitance, layout

[LTM2881](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/2881fj.pdf)s datasheet suggests a pair of embedded PCB capacitors to "minimize any high frequency differential voltages and substantially
reducing radiated emissions".

In the [eval board](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/demo-board-manual/dc1746af.pdf) and datasheet they suggest it to be done like this:

[image]

The the Eval Board .pdf states the following:

> 1 - Four layer PCB, allowing for isolated side to logic side
>   ‘bridge’ capacitor. The bridge capacitor is formed between
>   an inner layer of floating copper which overlaps
>   the logic side and isolated side ground planes. This
>   structure creates two series capacitors, each with approximately
>   0.008" of insulation, supporting the full
>   dielectric withstand rating of 2500VRMS. The bridge
>   capacitor provides a low impedance return path for
>   injected currents due to parasitic capacitances of the
>   LTM2881’s signal and power isolating elements.

[image]

I have failed to find the dimensions to the planes on the available .pdfs, and I would like to *not* have to resort rescaling the images with the known IC size to find out the dimensions (its a nice opportunity to learn something).

Its quite easy to find calculators for a single capacitor made of two planes on the PCB, but how do I calculate 2 capacitors in series with parts of one plane not overlapping? (Namely the parts of the Layer 2 - Ground Plane that do not overlap with Layer 1, do I ignore that?)

**p.s.:** or are the dimensions not that critical and a few pF are enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is 15mm by 10mm. Your overlap, on each side, looks to be 10mm by 20mm. The 8mil spacing, in 4layer PCB, is 1/5th mm.

Capacitance is E0*Er*Area/Distance = 9e-12Farad/meter * FR4=4 * 200mm^2/(1/5mm)

C (one cap) is 36e-12 * 200/0.2 * 1meter/1000mm
C = 36e-12 * 1000 / 1000 = 36 picoFarad.

Two in series is 18pF.

How accurate is this? aspect ratio is 10mm by 1/5mm or 50:1. The capacitor has less than 10% error.